# WPF MVVM - Monitor Changes to Bound Object (e.g. Enable Save if IsDirty)

Tags: wpf, mvvm

In WPF, using MVVM pattern (and using the MVVMLight toolkit), I am have a User Control that displays editable fields for a Product.  This UC is bound to the selected value from a ComboBox that lists all Products.

This all works fine, but in my Product class, I have a boolean field called IsDirty that is set to true when any property on the Product is updated.  **I would like my save button in the main view to be enabled whenever the IsDirty property is true on the selected Product (in the User Control).**  I can't figure out how to have the IsSaveEnabled property "watch" for changes in the SelectedProduct (basically when it becomes dirty).

I was able to accomplish this by using an event handler, but that attaches an event to each product selected and it seems dirty and clunky.  Is this something I'm missing on how to properly watch for changes to a bound object?

**Products.xaml** *(partial)*

```
<Grid DataContext="{Binding Source={StaticResource ProductsViewModel}}">
    <StackPanel>
        <ComboBox x:Name="ProductsComboBox" 
                  ItemsSource="{Binding Path=ProductList}" 
                  DisplayMemberPath="Name" 
                  SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedProduct}" />
        <uc:Product DataContext="{Binding SelectedItem, ElementName=ProductsComboBox}" />
        <Button Content="Save" IsEnabled="{Binding IsSaveEnabled}" Click="Button_Click" />
    </StackPanel>
</Grid>
```

**ProductsViewModel.cs** *(partial)*

```
public bool IsSaveEnabled
{
    get { return SelectedProduct.IsDirty; }
}

public ProductViewModel SelectedProduct
{
    get { return _selectedProduct; }
    set { 
        // I can use the next line, but it seems really clunky and creates a ton of event listeners
        // value.PropertyChanged += SelectedProduct_PropertyChanged;
        Set(() => SelectedProduct, ref _selectedProduct, value); 
        }
}

// This is the event handler that seems bad form and a duplication of functionality that is already in the Product class
//void SelectedProduct_PropertyChanged(object sender, System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
//    {
//        SelectedProperty.IsDirty = true;
//        RaisePropertyChanged(() => IsSaveEnabled);
//    }
```

Comment: "Seems bad form?"  I think the only smell is that it's a PITA to implement manually.  Yes, that's how you would do it.  You need to subscribe to PropertyChanged when a new SelectedProduct is added, and unsubscribe prior to SelectedProduct being changed.

Comment: Thanks for the comment Will.  Out of curiosity, how would I unsubscribe?  There is no "BeforeSelectionChanged" or "SelectionChanging" event on a combo box that would allow me to unsubscribe from the previously selected object.

Comment: Will, you can ignore my comment.  The code that d.moncada posted below clarified it for me... basically the "old" selection is in my private variable.  I can disassociate that before I reassign it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do it like this:

```
public class ProductsViewModel
{
    private bool _isSaveEnabled;

    public bool IsSaveEnabled
    {
        get { return _isSaveEnabled; }
        private set
        {
            _isSaveEnabled = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    public ProductViewModel SelectedProduct
    {
        get { return _selectedProduct; }
        set 
        { 
            if (value != _selectedProduct)
            {
                // unsubscribe from old selected product changes
                //
                _selectedProduct.PropertyChanged -= OnPropertyChanged;

                // subscribe to new selected product changes
                //
                value.PropertyChanged += OnPropertyChanged;

                _selectedProduct = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged();
            }
        }
    }

    private void OnPropertyChanged(object sender, System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        SelectedProperty.IsDirty = true;
        IsSaveEnabled = SelectedProperty.IsDirty;
    }   
}
```

The reason why you are seeing so many event handlers is because you are subscribing to a new event handler EVERY time selected product changes. You only want to do it for one, so make sure you unsubscribe from the old one before subscribing to the new one. Also, there's no need to do a RaisePropertyChanged for IsSaveEnabled, just raise the event inside its setter.

Comment: Thanks d.moncada... that answered my question

Answer (score 2):

You should probably be using a Command instead:

```
    public static RoutedCommand Command_Save = new RoutedCommand ( );

    void Command_Save_Executed ( object sender, ExecutedRoutedEventArgs e )
    {
         // save the product
    }

    void Command_Save_CanExecute ( object sender, CanExecuteRoutedEventArgs e )
    {
        e.CanExecute = SelectedProduct.IsDirty;
    }
```

XAML:

```
<Button Content="Save" Command="{x:Static MY:ProductsControl.Command_Save }" />
```

And bind it to the control (either in the ctor or in xaml):

```
            this.CommandBindings.Add( new CommandBinding( Command_SaveAs,
                                                      Command_SaveAs_Executed,
                                                      Command_SaveAs_CanExecute ) );
```

The command infrastructure will call your CanExecute event handler to disable/enable the button.

Comment: Byron, I accepted d.moncada's answer because it directly addressed my question, but your answer is valid as well.  I am debating whether or not to use the command pattern.  It can make things easier (as in this case) but it also carries some baggage (like a requirement on Windows.Forms).  Thanks for the detailed posting.